# Failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2554488617/target: no such file or directory

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-image, docker-build

New to docker, trying to build a Java Spring web app.
Created a Dockerfile in my application folder 'Feedback Collection System':

```
>     FROM openjdk:19
>     VOLUME /tmp
>     EXPOSE 8080
>     ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
>     ADD ${JAR_FILE} FeedbackColletionSystem.jar
>     ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Created an artifact, builded jar file in 'out' folder if its relevant.
Runed a command
C:\Users\myname\IdeaProjects\Feedback Collection System> docker build -t fcs .
And recieved such an error -

```
=> ERROR [2/2] ADD target/fcs-docker.jar app.jar                                                                  0.0s
------
  [2/2] ADD target/fcs-docker.jar app.jar:
------
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   3 |     EXPOSE 8080
   4 |     ARG JAR_FILE=target/fcs-docker.jar
   5 | >>> ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
   6 |     ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref c6c2b90b-d036-468a-af5f-109679f007da::ffr4qbgvxpsv1750xol8t3sou: 
failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2615739737/target: 
lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2615739737/target: no such file or directory
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The error message, in simpler words, says the `target` directory doesn't exist relative to the `.` directory in the `docker build` command.  Do you have the right path for the built jar file?

Comment: the built jar file has default path, like in the 'out' folder. What should be the right path?

Comment: Whatever that `out` directory path is needs to be in the value of `JAR_FILE`, either in the Dockerfile or in a `docker build --build-arg` option.

Comment: Thanks. I changed target/*.jar to my jar in project directoty and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems that jar is not created :Try to Right Click > Run as > Maven install and then try "docker build" command. It worked for me!

Comment: `Right Click` on what?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the jar file into the same folder as the Dockerfile